# SQL Server 2008 R2 Sales transaction Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a assignment due so any help would help a lot thank you!

Not sure if I did it right any help would be great thank you!

Create a trigger so that no sales transaction can be initially entered or modified that is larger than the credit limit. If the sales transaction is over the credit limit, roll back the transaction.

My Code

```
Create Trigger salesTransaction on Customers
For insert, update
as
--Get Credit limit
Declare @@Creditlimit money
select @@Creditlimit = CreditLimt from inserted i
Declare @@amount money
select @@amount = (p.Price * s.qtyOrdered) from inserted i
inner join Orders o
on i.CustomerNo = o.CustomerNo
inner join SalesDetail s
on s.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
inner join Products p
on (p.ManufactureID + p.ProductID) = (s.ManufactureID + s.ProductID)
where (i.CustomerNo = o.CustomerNo and o.CustomerNo = s.OrderNo and s.ManufactureID = p.ManufactureID and s.ProductID = p.ProductID)
if(@@amount > @@Creditlimit)
Begin
rollback transaction
End
```

My tables

```
Create Table Customers
(
CustomerNo char(4) 
Constraint ck_CustomerNoHas4positionsWithNumbers
Check(CustomerNo like'[0-9],[0-9],[0-9],[0-9]'),
Company varchar(50) not null,
CustomerRep char(3),
CreditLimt money default(20000.00),
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerNo)
)
Alter Table Customers
Add constraint fk_customerrep
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerRep) 
REFERENCES Salesreps(EmployeeNo)

Create Table Orders
(
OrderNo int,
OrderDate Date not null,
CustomerNo char(4) not null,
SalesRep char(3) not null
PRIMARY KEY(OrderNo)
)
Alter Table Orders
Add constraint fk_customerno
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNo)
REFERENCES Customers(CustomerNo),
constraint fk_salesrep
FOREIGN KEY (SalesRep)
REFERENCES Salesreps(EmployeeNo)
Create Table SalesDetail
(
SaleDetailID int,
ManufactureID char(3) Constraint ck_ManufactureIDFromSaleDetails check(ManufactureID like'[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]') not null,
ProductID char(5) Constraint ck_ProductIDSalesDetail check(ProductID like'[0-9],[0-9],[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]') not null,
OrderNo int,
qtyOrdered int
PRIMARY KEY(SaleDetailID)
)

Alter Table SalesDetail
add FOREIGN KEY (OrderNo)
REFERENCES Orders(OrderNo)

Alter Table SalesDetail 
Add constraint fk_SalesDetails_Mid_Pid
FOREIGN KEY (ManufactureID, ProductID) 
REFERENCES Products(ManufactureID, ProductID) 

Create Table Products
(
ManufactureID char(3) 
Constraint ck_ManufactureIDifItHasLettersOnly check(ManufactureID like'[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]'),
ProductID char(5) 
Constraint ck_ProductIDhasTwoLettersAndThreeNumbers check(ProductID like'[a-z],[a-z],[0-9],[0-9],[0-9]'),
Description varchar(50) not null,
Price money not null,
QtyOnHand int not null,
PRIMARY KEY(ManufactureID, ProductID)
)
```

Comment: And when you run it - does it do what you're looking for?? If not: what does it do?? Do you get an error anywhere'????

Comment: These lines here: `select @@Creditlimit = CreditLimt from inserted i` and `select @@amount = (p.Price * s.qtyOrdered) from inserted i` will fail horribly if your `Inserted` pseudo-table has more than one row.... and it might ! The trigger is run **one per statement** (which could be inserting multiple rows) - **NOT** once per row....

Comment: Do you realise that this condition, `on (p.ManufactureID + p.ProductID) = (s.ManufactureID + s.ProductID)`, may (and arguably will) render your query non-[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)? Is it really necessary to join the tables that way? Or is that expression just the result of your being a bit too lazy to write this instead: `on p.ManufactureID = s.ManufactureID and p.ProductID = s.ProductID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- **WHY** is the trigger on `Customer` ?? You don't want to check these conditions when a new **customer** is inserted (or updated) - but rather when a new **Order** is inserted - no??
- Your code doesn't take into account the fact that the trigger will be called **once per statement** and that this one statement can very well insert (or update) **multiple orders** at once - therefore, the `Inserted` pseudo table **can** (and will!) contain multiple entries, and your code doesn't work with multiple entries....

So my take would be:

- Put the trigger on the `Orders` table
- Make it so that it can handle multiple rows in `Inserted`
- I count the number of rows I find where the order total exceeds the customer's `CreditLimit` - if that's greater than zero (at least one order exceeds that limit), I roll back the transaction.

Here's the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER salesTransaction ON dbo.Orders
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  --Get Credit limit
  DECLARE @Count INT

  SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(*)
  FROM Inserted i
  INNER JOIN dbo.Orders o ON i.CustomerNo = o.CustomerNo
  INNER JOIN SalesDetail s ON s.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
  INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ManufactureID = s.ManufactureID AND m.Product = s.ProductID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Customer c ON o.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo
  WHERE (p.Price * s.qtyOrdered) > c.CreditLimit

  IF (@Count > 0)
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```